# How are daemon processes started in Python?

Tags: python, rest, fork, wsgi, gevent

I want to start two daemon process in python like following code:

```
daemon_main = DaemonImplMain()
daemon_check = DaemonImplCheck()
pid = os.fork()
if pid:
    daemon_main.start()
else:
    daemon_check.start()
```

in this code , daemon_main is a http server with wsgi, daemon_check is a check process. But the daemon_main cannot accept request when i run this code.

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) on daemon threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `DaemonImplMain` and `DaemonImplCheck` inherit from `threading.Thread`? If so, then you can set the [daemon to true](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) before starting the threads.

For eg.

```
daemon_main.daemon = True
daemon_main.start()
```

Same goes for `daemon_check`